# How can I redraw only certain matplotlib artists?

Tags: python, matplotlib, redraw, blit

I'm working on a custom interactive figure for electrophysiology data, anywhere from 10-400 lines (EEG or MEG data channels) plotted as a LineCollection with offsets.  It is often useful to have a vertical line to assess how signal features on different channels align temporally, so I have a `button_press_event` listener that creates an `axvline` (or updates the `xdata` of the line, if it already exists).  Redrawing the `axvline` is expensive if there are lots of channels in the LineCollection, but the supposedly more efficient redraw method (`ax.draw_artist(my_vline)`) doesn't work at all (it is quite possible that I am simply misunderstanding how `draw_artist` is supposed to work).

**Code for reproduction**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()


def make_vline(event):
    ax = event.inaxes
    if getattr(ax, 'my_vline', None) is None:
        ax.my_vline = ax.axvline(event.xdata, linewidth=4, color='r')
    else:
        ax.my_vline.set_xdata(event.xdata)
    # I thought any 1 of these 3 lines would move the vline to the click location:
    ax.draw_artist(ax.my_vline)  # this has no visible effect
    ax.redraw_in_frame()  # TypeError (see below for traceback)
    ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()  # works, but slow when figure has many lines


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
callback_id = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', make_vline)
```

**Actual outcome**

- If I use the `ax.draw_artist(ax.my_vline)` line, outcome is a blank axes no matter where I click (unless I then resize the figure, which triggers a redraw and then the line appears).
- If i use the `ax.redraw_in_frame()` line, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/mnedev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 224, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-1-08572d18e6b3>", line 11, in make_vline
    ax.redraw_in_frame()
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/mnedev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2778, in redraw_in_frame
    stack.push(artist.set_visible, artist.get_visible())
TypeError: push() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

- if I use `ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()` it works as expected, but is really slow once the figure has actual data in it. Here is a longer code snippet you can run locally to see the slowness:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
plt.ion()
rng = np.random.default_rng()


def make_vline(event):
    ax = event.inaxes
    if getattr(ax, 'my_vline', None) is None:
        ax.my_vline = ax.axvline(event.xdata, linewidth=4, color='r', zorder=3)
    else:
        ax.my_vline.set_xdata(event.xdata)
    ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()  # works, but slow when figure has many lines


def add_line_collection(ax):
    n_chans = 400
    n_times = 10001
    xs = np.linspace(0, 10, n_times)
    ys = rng.normal(size=(n_chans, n_times)) * 1e-6
    segments = [np.vstack((xs, ys[n])).T for n in range(n_chans)]
    yoffsets = np.arange(n_chans)
    offsets = np.vstack((np.zeros_like(yoffsets), yoffsets)).T
    lc = LineCollection(segments, offsets=offsets, linewidths=0.5, colors='k')
    ax.add_collection(lc)
    ax.set_xlim(xs[0], xs[-1])
    ax.set_ylim(yoffsets[0] - 0.5, yoffsets[-1] + 0.5)
    ax.set_yticks(yoffsets)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
add_line_collection(ax)
callback_id = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', make_vline)
```

**Questions**

1. when would `ax.draw_artist(my_artist)` actually work / what is it supposed to do?
2. Is my example a case where blitting would be beneficial?
3. Any other ideas for how to speed up (re)drawing here?

**Matplotlib version**

- Operating system: Xubuntu 20.04
- Matplotlib version: 3.3.1 (conda-forge)
- Matplotlib backend: Qt5Agg
- Python version: 3.8.5
- Jupyter version (if applicable): n/a
- Other libraries: numpy 1.19.1 (conda-forge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with blitting, based on [the MPL blitting tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/advanced/blitting.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
plt.ion()
rng = np.random.default_rng()


def make_vline(event):
    fig.canvas.restore_region(fig.my_bg)
    ax = event.inaxes
    if getattr(ax, 'my_vline', None) is None:
        ax.my_vline = ax.axvline(event.xdata, linewidth=4, color='r', zorder=3)
    else:
        ax.my_vline.set_xdata(event.xdata)
    ax.draw_artist(ax.my_vline)
    ax.figure.canvas.blit()
    ax.figure.canvas.flush_events()


def add_line_collection(ax):
    n_chans = 400
    n_times = 10001
    xs = np.linspace(0, 10, n_times)
    ys = rng.normal(size=(n_chans, n_times)) * 1e-6
    segments = [np.vstack((xs, ys[n])).T for n in range(n_chans)]
    yoffsets = np.arange(n_chans)
    offsets = np.vstack((np.zeros_like(yoffsets), yoffsets)).T
    lc = LineCollection(segments, offsets=offsets, linewidths=0.5, colors='k')
    ax.add_collection(lc)
    ax.set_xlim(xs[0], xs[-1])
    ax.set_ylim(yoffsets[0] - 0.5, yoffsets[-1] + 0.5)
    ax.set_yticks(yoffsets)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
add_line_collection(ax)
callback_id = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', make_vline)
plt.pause(0.1)
fig.my_bg = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(fig.bbox)
```

Note that this will not work if the figure is resized, you would need to rerun the `copy_from_bbox` line in a resize listener.